# Scrape data from table whose elements don't load immediately

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I've been trying to scrape data from a table using selenium, but when I run the code, it only gets the header of the table.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.panamacompra.gob.pa/Inicio/#!/busquedaAvanzada?BusquedaRubros=true&IdRubro=41')
driver.implicitly_wait(100)
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/table/tbody')
print(t.text)
```

I also tried finding element by tag name using table, without luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need wait until loader disappear, you can use `invisibility_of_element_located`, utilize `WebDriverWait` and `expected_conditions`. For the table you can use `css_selector` instead your `xpath`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.panamacompra.gob.pa/Inicio/#!/busquedaAvanzada?BusquedaRubros=true&IdRubro=41')

time.sleep(2)
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//img[@src="images/loading.gif"]')))
table = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.table_asearch.table.table-bordered.table-striped.table-hover.table-condensed')
print(table.text)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.panamacompra.gob.pa/Inicio/#!/busquedaAvanzada?BusquedaRubros=true&IdRubro=41')
driver.implicitly_wait(100)

table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/table/tbody')
number=2
while(number<12):
    content = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr['+str(number)+']')
    print(content.text)
    number+=1
```

The XPATH in 'table' is just the header, the actual content is this : '//*[@id="body"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr['+str(number)+']' , that's why you are not getting any content different than the header. Since the XPATH in the rows are like ...../tr[2],...../tr[3],...../tr[4], etc, Im using the str(number) < 12 , to get all the raws, you can also try with 50 rows a the time, is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `requests` and mimic the POST request by the page as much faster

```
import requests

data = {'METHOD': '0','VALUE': '{"BusquedaRubros":"true","IdRubro":"41","Inicio":0}'}
r = s.post('http://www.panamacompra.gob.pa/Security/AmbientePublico.asmx/cargarActosOportunidadesDeNegocio', data=data).json()
print(r['listActos'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is loading the table (happens fairly quickly) and then assuming it is done, since it's never given a chance to load the table rows (happens more slowly). One way around this is to repeatedly try to find an element that won't appear until the table is finished loading.

This is FAR from the most elegant solution (and there's probably Selenium libraries that do it better), but you can wait for the table by checking to see if a new table row can be found, and if not, sleep for 1 second before trying again.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.panamacompra.gob.pa/Inicio/#!/busquedaAvanzada?BusquedaRubros=true&IdRubro=41')

wvar = 0
while(wvar == 0):
  try:
    #try loading one of the elements we want to read
    el = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[3]')
    wvar = 1
  except NoSuchElementException:
    #not loaded yet
    print('table body empty, waiting...')
    time.sleep(1)

print('table loaded!')

#element got loaded; reload the table
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/table/tbody')
print(table.text)
```